# For Loop with If statement onlyreturns first element

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to feed a vector into a function which checks every element and assigns the corresponding element from the list to the proper if statement.

The output should look like this:

> 10
>   11 
>   17 
>   40 
>   370

Somehow I am only receiving the first element

> 370

and the loop is breaking up.The code looks like the following:

```
def dosomething(thelist):
    period_unit = []
    for period in thelist:
        period = period.lower()        
        if period[-1:] == "d":
            period_unit = 1
        elif period[-1:] == "m":
            period_unit = 30
        elif period[-1:] == "w":
            period_unit = 7
        elif period[-1:] == "y":
            period_unit = 360
        elif period == "dummy":
            period_object = 0
            return period_object
        else:
            raise Exception("Something went wrong")
        period_object = 10 + period_unit
    return period_object   

if __name__ == '__main__':

    date = ["dummy", "1d", "1W", "1M", "1Y"]

    test = dosomething(date )
    print(test)
```

Comment: You did not define any of these values in your if-block: 10 11 17 40.

Comment: you have 2 return statements. if period == 'dummy' then function will close and return the period object.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, Thanks for your answer. The answer is a addition of the value in the if-statementand below the period_object e.g. for the statement >elif period[-1:] == "m": period_unit = 30 
menast that period_unit should be added to the 10 below defined. Hope it is more clear?

Comment: You don't save any of the `period_object` values you generate, so each one overwrites the one before it. You're not getting the *first* value, you're getting the *last*.

Comment: @Tkanno, also if you dont have the return statement it does not work and shows only the element 370 which is (360 for the condition 360 plus the 10 defined below.

Comment: @glibdud is right. you need to append period to your period_unit list which you initalised but never use. also if you want a list to be the output, then you need to return period_unit, not period

Comment: Also note that your `elif period == "dummy":` block will never run, as anything that would trigger this will have first triggered the `elif period[-1:] == "y":` block.

Comment: @glibdud, yes you are right. But somehow I am not sure how I can make that? Do you have an example? Thanks

Comment: @JonDoen See Tkanno's comment.

Comment: @glibdud, can you be more explicit with the dummy? Also maybe showing an example how to handle it better?

Comment: @JonDoe If `period` contains `"dummy"`, it will execute the `elif period[-1] == "y"` block because it ends in "y", thus it will not hit the `elif period == "dummy"` block.

Comment: @glibdud, you are right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reassign `period_unit` everytime.

You want to do something like:

```
def dosomething(thelist):
    period_unit = []
    for period in thelist:
        period = period.lower()
        curr_period_unit = None
        if period == "dummy":
            curr_period_unit = 0
        elif period[-1] == "d":
            curr_period_unit = 1
        elif period[-1] == "m":
            curr_period_unit = 30
        elif period[-1] == "w":
            curr_period_unit = 7
        elif period[-1] == "y":
            curr_period_unit = 360
        else:
            raise Exception("Something went wrong")
        period_unit.append(10 + curr_period_unit)
    return period_unit
```

And then it works as expected:

```
>>> date = ["dummy", "1d", "1W", "1M", "1Y"]
>>> dosomething(date)
[10, 11, 17, 40, 370]
>>> ' '.join(str(item) for item in dosomething(date))
'10 11 17 40 370'
```

Comment: Found the problem. Thanksa  lot.